# How to fix error: could not convert string to float: 'lemonde'

Tags: python

I have a column called sources, and at first I had to get rid of the '-' character but now I am getting the error, could not convert string to float: 'lemonde'. Lemonde was originally le-monde before I got rid of the character. I tried .astype(float) but still got the same error . I don't know what else to do.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from datetime import datetime

##change date 
TrainDF['Date'] = pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(TrainDF['Date']))
TestDF['Date'] = pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(TestDF['Date']))

##get rid of '-' in column
TrainDF['Source'] = TrainDF['Source'].str.replace('-', '')
TestDF['Source'] = TestDF['Source'].str.replace('-', '')

##convert source to float
TrainDF['Source'] = TrainDF['Source'].astype(float)
TestDF['Source'] = TestDF['Source'].astype(float)  

## Instantiate
MyModelNB= MultinomialNB()

## FIT
MyNB=MyModelNB.fit(TrainDF, TrainLabels)
#print(MyNB.classes_)
#print(MyNB.class_count_)
#print(MyNB.feature_log_prob_)


Prediction = MyModelNB.predict(TestDF)
print(np.round(MyModelNB.predict_proba(TestDF),2))

## COnfusion Matrix Accuracies
cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(TestLabels, Prediction)
print("\nThe confusion matrix is:")
print(cnf_matrix)
```

here is a sample of the dataset for more insight: [image: 1]

Comment: _at first I had to get rid of the '-' character_ Why did you have to get rid of it?

Comment: honestly im not sure why-- I think I thought it would help with the error. Do you think I don't need to

Comment: Why do you want to convert `Source` to `float`?  In `Source` you have strings like `wired`, `'le-monde` - what `float` values do you expect for `wired`, And what `float` value you expect for `le-monde`? If you need to use number instead of strings then you have to enumerate them - create list with all words in `Source` and assign numbers to words and replace words with numbers in `Source`. Some modules should have special function for enumeration.

Comment: See [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)